# For which values of $k$ the Inner product is well defined

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

> set Inner product with $\mathbb{R}^2x\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$
> $<(x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)>=x_1y_1-3x_1y_2-3x_2y_1+kx_2y_2$
> For which values of $k$ the Inner product is well defined?>

Hi there , I have this question and I'm not sure I solved it right.
When checking for "Positive semi-definite" I get -

$<(x_1,x_2),(x_1,x_2)>=x_1^2-6x_1x_2+kx_2^2 \ge 0$

Here I'm not sure what to do.  If I do Trinomial I get that for $k\ge9$ the equation is $\ge0$ for all $x_1,x_2\in \mathbb{R}$.
So this is the solution? I'm not sure because if $0<k<9$ then for some $x_1,x_2\in \mathbb{R}$ in might be true and for some it might be false...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "If I do trinomial"?

Comment: Note that the function is only an inner product if for **every** $x_1,x_2 \in \Bbb R$, we have
$$
\langle (x_1,x_2),(x_1,x_2) \rangle \geq 0.
$$

Comment: By Trinomial I mean - trying to change the equation into the form $(x_1-\sqrt(k)x_2)^2$ , For that to be the equation and $\ge 0$ .$k$ must be equal to $9$

Comment: @BenGrossmann oh Okay so the solution is $k \ge 0$ I guess

Comment: No, the solution is $k \geq 9$

Comment: @BenGrossmann yeah sorry thats what I meant , just a typo and I can't edit it for now

Comment: Great. Actually, I was wrong: it is true that the positive semidefinite property only requires that $k \geq 9$, but for the inner product to be (positive) *definite*, we require $k > 9$.